# Django/Postgres fulltext search - exclude if value contains <STRING>

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-orm, django-searchvector

Trying to use `Postgres` search in `Django` using `SearchVector` and I want to exclude results if contain a given string. Is it possible?

Example from docs:

```
Entry.objects.annotate(search=SearchVector('body_text', 'blog__tagline')).filter(search='Cheese')
```

What if I want to exclude objects whose `blog__tagline` contains "queso"?

I can't exclude objects with "queso" before annotation because I want to include them when a search is not performed.

Answer (score 0):

```py
Entry.objects.exclude(blog__tagline__icontains='queso').annotate(search=SearchVector('body_text', 'blog__tagline')).filter(search='Cheese')
```

if you need a quick fix, i'd recommend `exclude`.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest two solutions:
First, you can apply logical operators on your `SearchQuery` objects.

```py
cheese = SearchQuery('cheese')
not_cheese = ~SearchQuery('cheese')
cheese_and_not_queso = SearchQuery('cheese') & ~SearchQuery('queso')
...
Entry.objects.annotate(search=SearchVector('body_text', 'blog__tagline')).filter(search=cheese_and_not_queso)
```

Second, you can use search operators in your query, but you need some additional configurations. `filter(search='Cheese')` it creates a SearchQuery is equivalent to `filter(search=SearchQuery('Cheese', search_type='plain'))`. In plain search type (see [Postgres doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-controls.html)), search operators and special full-text search characters are stripped and we don't want that. `search_type` accepts four modes: 'plain', 'phrase', 'raw' and 'websearch'. If you use 'raw' as search_type, you can use these operators in you query string:

```
& (AND) 
| (OR)
! (NOT)
<-> (FOLLOWED BY)
```

So you can change your query to `SearchQuery("cheese & !queso", search_type='raw')`.
What about other search types? 'phrase' is like 'plain' in stripping behavior but 'websearch' able us to use web search engine syntax (like Google) in our query. So query can be rephrased in `SearchQuery("cheese -queso", search_type='websearch')`

[Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/postgres/search/) on full-text search and Postgres and [Postgres doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-controls.html) on controlling searches are best places to learn more.